# SQuirrel Call Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, squirrel-sql, db2-zos

I am trying to call a DB2 stored procedure from Squirrel.
I can call the stored procedure successfully from the DB2 command line
processor.

```
 CALL PIPPOOWN.PIPPO
('04','prov','0001','provprov')
```

I append `;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;` to connection string for the database.

```
jdbc:db2://xx.xx.x.xx:50001/DB2XYX:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;
```

But when I try this in Squirrel I get this error message. I am running

```
Error: [jcc][10413][10940][4.19.49]
Analisi della sostituzione letterale non riuscita per la chiamata della procedura a DB2 per z/OS.
Testo SQL non riuscito CALL
SP_XXXXX('XX','prova').
ERRORCODE=-4463, SQLSTATE=42601
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -4463


2021-02-02 12:01:03,409 [Thread-6] ERROR net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.util.DefaultExceptionFormatter  - Exception occurred while formatting:  null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.db2.DB2JCCExceptionFormatter.format(DB2JCCExceptionFormatter.java:93)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.util.DefaultExceptionFormatter.format(DefaultExceptionFormatter.java:68)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.Session.formatException(Session.java:1195)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.mainpanel.SQLExecutionHandler.sqlExecutionException(SQLExecutionHandler.java:458)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.handleError(SQLExecuterTask.java:621)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.runDirect(SQLExecuterTask.java:264)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.run(SQLExecuterTask.java:137)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.util.TaskExecuter.run(TaskExecuter.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i updated jdbc drivers but i didn't fix.

[image]

DB2 Version: 11.01

If I use IBM DATA STUDIO or I use a DB2 AIX it works.

***EDIT 03/02/2021***

I downloaded "IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ (JCC Driver)"  [Version 11.5.4](https://epwt-www.mybluemix.net/software/support/trial/cst/programwebsite.wss?siteId=854&h=null&p=null), then I configured it to use db2jcc4.jar
Now it gives the following error:

```
NO AUTHORIZED PROCEDURE NAMED PIPPOOWN.PIPPO HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND. 
SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.26.14 SQL Code: -440, SQL State: 42884
```

but if i use IBM DATA STUDIO with the same user and statements i get no error

Stored Procedure "PIPPO" - GRANT

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE "PIPPOOWN"."PIPPO" TO "ALL";
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE "PIPPOOWN"."PIPPO" TO "PUBLICB";
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE "PIPPOOWN"."PIPPO" TO "PIPPOOWN" WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE "PIPPOOWN"."PIPPO" TO "USERWEB";
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE "PIPPOOWN"."PIPPO" TO PUBLIC;
```

Stored Procedure "PIPPO" - Distribution Options (using Data Studio)

[image]

CURRENT_PATH BY SQUIRREL

```
SELECT CURRENT_PATH FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

RESULTS
-----------------------------------------------
"SYSIBM","SYSFUN","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM","PIPPOOWN"
```

Finally, I can't find any error in the Squirrel log.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 04/02/2021**

I excecute the call statement on Squirrel, enabling the JDBC log and I found this error:

```
[jcc][Time:2021-02-04-10:16:23.549][Thread:Thread-4][Statement@f7f204]**execute (CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC('xx')) called**
[jcc][Time:2021-02-04-10:16:23.549][Thread:Thread-4][Statement@f7f204]stmt_bidiTransform (CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC('xx')) called
[jcc][Time:2021-02-04-10:16:23.549][Thread:Thread-4][Statement@f7f204]**stmt_bidiTransform not enabled (CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC('xx')) called**
[jcc][t4][time:2021-02-04-10:16:23.549][Thread:Thread-4][tracepoint:1][Request.flush]
[jcc][t4]        SEND BUFFER: EXCSQLSTT              (ASCII)           (EBCDIC)
...
.....
**com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException
**  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:810)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.b(k4.java:2471)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.c(k4.java:2452)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.n(ab.java:914)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.f(ab.java:156)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.e(p.java:81)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.av.k(av.java:175)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.ao(k4.java:2413)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.a(k4.java:3383)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.e(k4.java:1131)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k4.execute(k4.java:1110)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.StatementWrapper.execute(StatementWrapper.java:168)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.processQuery(SQLExecuterTask.java:361)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.runDirect(SQLExecuterTask.java:214)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.session.SQLExecuterTask.run(SQLExecuterTask.java:137)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.util.TaskExecuter.run(TaskExecuter.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

For comparing the different logs, I also activate the IBM DATA STUDIO JDBC log (where the CALL statements work correctly) and I noticed that a prepareCall() is done before executing execute().

*IBM DATA STUDIO*

```
[jcc][Time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.381][Thread:Worker-19][Connection@97f8a03c]prepareCall (CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC('XX')) called
[jcc] [time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.383][Thread:Worker-19][tracepoint:4000]LiteralInfo entry,sql:CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC('XX')
[jcc] [time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.387][Thread:Worker-19][tracepoint:4005]LiteralInfo.return,OriginalSQL:CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC('XX'), modifiedSQL:CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC(?), literalCount=1, parmCount=1[CHARACTER(XX)]
[jcc][Time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.390][Thread:Worker-19][Connection@97f8a03c]prepareCall () returned MappedCallableStatement@691cf97[com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement@88958c83]
[jcc][Time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.390][Thread:Worker-19][Connection@97f8a03c]prepareCall () returned MappedCallableStatement@691cf97[com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement@88958c83]
[jcc][Thread:Worker-19][SystemMonitor:stop] core: 9.5471ms | network: 0.0ms | server: 0.0ms 
[jcc][Time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.390][Thread:Worker-19][CallableStatement@88958c83]setMaxRows (0) called
[jcc][Time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.390][Thread:Worker-19][CallableStatement@88958c83]setString (1, XX) called
[jcc][Thread:Worker-19][SystemMonitor:start] 
[jcc][Time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.390][Thread:Worker-19][CallableStatement@88958c83]execute () called
[jcc][Time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.390][Thread:Worker-19][CallableStatement@88958c83]stmt_bidiTransform (CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC(?)) called
[jcc][Time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.390][Thread:Worker-19][CallableStatement@88958c83]stmt_bidiTransform not enabled (CALL OWNER1.SP_ABC(?)) called
[jcc][t4][time:2021-02-03-20:52:10.390][Thread:Worker-19][tracepoint:1][Request.flush]


I looked in the [IBM documentation][4] and it seems that in order to call SP with parameters in the Z/OS environment, it is necessary to perform a PreparedStatement.
```

At this point I think it’s a Squirrel BUG...

Comment: Please append `;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;` to your connection string for the database, and retry, then show the new full exception by editing your question.  You should also try from a *different*  JDBC application (e.g. IBM Data Studio,  DBeaver, DBVizualizer etc).

Comment: It appears that your issue is caused by Squirrel-SQL configuration somehow.  Why are you using db2jcc.jar instead of db2jcc4.jar?   If it works correctly fro IBM Data Studio (which normally uses db2jcc4.jar ), then you should configure squirrel to use the same `db2jcc4.jar` that IBM Data Studio is using (along with the same db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar).

Comment: A jdbc trace will show exactly what's happening under the covers, refer to the Db2 Knowledge Centre for details of configuring this on your workstation. A comparison of the working-trace (Data Studio) and the failing-trace( squirrel-sql) can also show the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to open a BUG: [squirrel-sql:bugs#1457](https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/1457/) Call Stored Procedure with input parameters on DB2 z/os

Comment: Good luck with that. I suggest you emphasise in the bug report that the issue is only reproducible with Db2-for-Z/OS and will not reproduce with Db2-for-LUW/cloud.  Access to Z/OS will be the limiting factor for testing any fixes, although some people have emulators.